# Reading and extracting info from .img file

Tags: image

I am trying to extract information from a .img file but could not find any way to do that. Is there any way to read .img file preferably as a dictionary?

Thanks

Comment: I can open the .img file with ENVI but need an automatic way to do that.

Comment: please check this first https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask